How to use ChoiceField and ModelChoiceField with allauth Templates?
Based on the default allauth Templates I want to build a Custom SignUp Form which also includes ChoiceField and ModelChoiceField. Therefore I did the following adjustments:
accounts/models.py
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    SALUTATION = (
        ('m', _('Mr')),
        ('f', _('Mrs')),
    )

    salutation = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=SALUTATION,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    country = models.ForeignKey(
        Country,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        verbose_name=_('Country'),
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )

accounts/forms.py
class CustomSignupForm(forms.Form):
    salutation = forms.ChoiceField(widget=Select, choices=CustomUser.SALUTATION, initial=CustomUser.SALUTATION)
    country = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Country.objects.all(), initial=Country.objects.all())

templates/allauth/elements/field.html
{% load allauth %}
{% if attrs.type == "select" %}
    <select name="{{ attrs.name }}" id="{{ attrs.id }}" class="form-select mb-3">
        {% for option in attrs.value %}
            <option value="{% if option.0 %}{{ option.0 }}{% else %}{{ option.id }}{% endif %}">
                {% if option.1 %}
                    {{ option.1 }}
                {% else %}
                    {{ option }}
                {% endif %}
            </option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
{% elif attrs.type == "checkbox" or attrs.type == "radio" %}
...


Options only get populated to attrs.value when passing 'initial' parameter in the form. Shouldn't this be provided by 'choices' or 'queryset' parameter instead? Is there an option to get the values from attrs object in a different way?

initial expects one element, right now you pass all, so a collection of elements.

initial=… [Django-doc] expects one element, right now you pass all, so a collection of elements, so:
class CustomSignupForm(forms.Form):
    salutation = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=Select,
        choices=CustomUser.SALUTATION,
        initial=CustomUser.SALUTATION,
    )
    country = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Country.objects.all(),
        initial=Country.objects.get('United States'),
    )

But without setting initial parameter for all available choices, I don't get them populated to the template at all. attrs.value shows up as 'None' because it seems not to recognize choices or queryset parameters.

@CodeResearcher: but value is not the set of options, it is the selected value. You use .optgroup: https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/forms/templates/django/forms/widgets/select.html

@CodeResearcher: that being said, is there a reason why you don't let Django render the form, and perhaps add some CSS. Forms are way more complicated thing than it appears to be. The widgets have been rewritten some time, because it turns out there were still cases not fully covered.

ah ok, thank you! but how do I pass all available choices to my template when not using attrs.value? Because by just setting choices=CustomUser.SALUTATION the Choicefield on the form stays empty.

@CodeResearcher: choices lists what items you can pick from, and initial/value the items you picked.  If you later submit the form, Django will check this, so just swapping choices and initial might fix the rendering issue, but then will fail when you submit the vlaue.

The templates field.html and fields.html got adjusted today, so they can also handle ChoiceField and ModelChoiceField properly by passing choices parameter:
https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/commit/1eac57caaab22d40b1df99b272b9f34c795212cc
Than it can be used like this:
class CustomUserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    salutation = forms.ChoiceField(widget=Select(attrs={'placeholder': 'Salutation'}), choices=CustomUser.SALUTATION)
    country = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=Select(attrs={'placeholder': 'Country'}), queryset=Country.objects.all())

